# Bayesian Statistics Theorem

Tags: probability

Suppose a voter poll for a presidential election is taken in three states. In state A, we find that
55% of voters support the Republican candidate. In state B, we finnd that 60% of voters support the
Republican candidate. In state C, we find that 45% of voters support the Republican candidate. Of
the total population of the three states combined, 50% live in state A, 30% live in state B, and 20%
live in state C. Given that a voter supports the Republican candidate, what is the probability that the
voter lives in state A?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying your question as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Recall Bayes Theorem $ P(A|R) =\frac{P(R|A)P(A)}{P(R)} $ 
and the total probability rule $ P(R) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(R|X_i)P(X_i) $.

Is there any way to use the total probability rule to fill in the unknown values in Bayes Theorem?

Comment: Sorry about that @Glen_b, does the edit help?